# Get unexpected arguments when calling function from WCF services using LINQ 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, wcf

I have created a WCF web service using LINQ and was trying to call the `PatientRegistration` function. However, when I called the function there are a few arguments added in which I have no idea where they are come from. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Function in WCF Service:

```
public Boolean PatientRegistration(
    String HealthInsuranceNO,
    String FirstName,
    String LastName,
    int PhoneNumber,
    String Address,
    String Email)
{
    DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();

    if (HealthInsuranceNO != ""
        && FirstName != ""
        && LastName != ""
        && Address != ""
        && PhoneNumber != 0)
    {
        Patient p = new Patient();
        {
            p.HealthInsuranceNO = HealthInsuranceNO;
            p.FirstName = FirstName;
            p.LastName = LastName;
            p.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            p.Address = Address;
            p.Email = Email;
        };

        dc.Patients.InsertOnSubmit(p);

        dc.SubmitChanges();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And also:

```
[OperationContract]
Boolean PatientRegistration(
    String HealthInsuranceNO,
    String FirstName,
    String LastName,
    int PhoneNumber,
    String Address,
    String Email);
```

I got three more arguments that the system expect me to fill in and they are

```
bool PhoneNumberspecified,
out bool PatientmentRegistrationResult,
out bool PatientmentRegistrationResultSpecified
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are creating the `proxy` on the client using "Add Web Reference". You should use "Add Service Reference" for generating the right proxy.

The difference is the serializer they use. Adding a web reference uses `XmlSerializer` and adding Service reference uses a `DataContractSerializer`. It's the `XmlSerializer` which adds those paramters, one represents the data itself, and one specifies whether or not the data is actually present.

Comment: Thank your for your advice, but I am pretty sure that I need to add web reference according to instructions from the school lecture sheet.

Comment: Ok, just keep in mind that the way microsoft says for consuming a WCF service is adding a service reference. Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691.aspx.